# Magento 2: Collection Query addFieldToFilter Loop Issue

Tags: collection, query, magento2.1.6

I have below code

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
$customModel = $objectManager->get('\Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Index\Collection');

$orderIdsArray = array(3123,3124);

if(count($orderIdsArray) > 0 ){
    foreach($orderIdsArray as $orderId){
        $oId = $orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if($oId->getId()){
            $items = $oId->getAllItems();
            if (count($items) > 0 && count($items) == 1) {
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $products = $customModel->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $item->getProductId());
                    echo $products->getSelect()->__toString().'='.count($products); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First query it print

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '2482')
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '2482') AND (`product_id` = '1') <-- WRONG
```

How can i get below ones?

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '1') <-- CORRECT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a try -

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $products = clone $customModel;
    $products->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $item->getProductId());
    echo $products->getSelect()->__toString().'='.count($products); 
}
```

Comment: Nope still same issue

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following line after every time you get your products in the loop

```
$products->getSelect()->reset('where');
```

for testing add it after

```
echo $products->getSelect()->__toString().'='.count($products);
```

Comment: Already tried this one. Not working :(

Comment: For me worked fine though

Comment: $products->clear()->getSelect()->reset('where');
Also It's worked